# How can I achieve a 'warm' scene in Unity using post processing effects?

Tags: unity, shaders, lighting, post-processing

I've recently fallen inlove with this [Cozy Tavern scene by Beholder](https://sketchfab.com/models/6a78673634d54e059f7c370b105a41cc), and am looking to replicate it's feel the best I can in unity as a learning exercise.

A lot of the scene's depth is added through lighting, and post processing effects. The lighting is simple enough to where I think I can reasonably replicate it with some trial/error using different lights, however the post-processing is where I get a bit lost.

It's clear that there are a few different effects going on, one of which being the increase in saturation, and a limited depth of field.

My guess is that I would need to write a few different shaders (or rather one?) to add these effects? Any input as to how I could achieve similar results would be greatly appreciated.

---

**No Post Processing:**
[image: No Post Processing]

---

**With Post Processing:**
[image: Post Processing]

Comment: Looking at the image I spot colour grading, depth of field, and bloom effects, and maybe a subtle vignette, all of which are supported by the [standard Unity post-processing stack](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Stack.html), so you might not need to write new shaders at all. Have you tried playing with this asset?

Comment: Relatively new to Unity, so I didn't even know Unity had a standard stack, I will definitely have a look - thank you!